# Is this design possible with ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've been asked to do the front end for a web app, and to use ExtJS specifically.

I've been working through a couple of tutorials, but I've not seen much variation on the default ExtJS look and feel except for some subtle changes to the colors and what not.

The design I've been handed seems to be a radical departure from the standard ExtJs look and feel. So before I head down a dead end or start chasing wild geese, I wondered wether any ExtJS experts out there could point out any potential pit falls in the design, or is everything do-able?

[The design is here...](http://www.tomelders.com/public/03_IE_VISTA.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible, *IF* you have pretty strong CSS skills and not afraid to customize the JS components to some extent.  You're going to be overriding a lot of the default stylesheet content to get this look-and-feel, and for certain aspects it may require tweaking the markup generated by a component by default.  If you are new to Ext JS this may be a bit daunting, but once you wrap your head around it you can do about anything you want.

Comment: What I've figured out so far is, basically, it would be easier to not use ExtJS. But that's not an option.

Comment: Easier and better I might add.

Comment: Ext is just a tool like anything else.  If you fight against it or hold a grudge because it's not the tool you would prefer, then yes, your experience is likely to be a bit painful.

Comment: excellent point. Rarely does the tool really stand in your way, it's all about your willingness to learn and your ability to wield the tool well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

ExtJS is designed to be easily customised. With some CSS knowledge, you should not have problems getting that look and feel.

Just as an example, you may want to check out this service, which uses a very customized  ExtJS skin:

- [Filespots - Find Out More](http://www.filespots.com/find-out-more.html)
- [ExtJS Forum - Disussing Filespots](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=14034)

[Filespots using ExtJS http://www.filespots.com/static/web/images/en/invite-users.jpg](http://www.filespots.com/static/web/images/en/invite-users.jpg)